# Change access permissions in reconmap rest api laminas

Tags: php, rest, roles, laminas

I would like to set Projects->Vault option access permission for client role in Reconmap rest API laminas.  By default in Reconmap rest API, Vault permission from projects is not accessible for client.

How can I achieve this?

Tried code in Services/Security/Permissions.php for access permission changes as per role.